# Printing a positional numeric system in C

Tags: c, printing

I'm trying to write a function that print a positional numeric system with given base and number of digits. For example, with Base = 2 and nDigits = 3 the output have to be like this:

```
000
001
010
011
...
111
```

Now, I've tried to do something but I've only failed. Consider that I can't store the numbers, I just have to print them, that's why I use a dynamic allocation of a 'support' array. That's what I tried to do so far, obviously not doing what it's intended to... I think the only correct part is to print all the combinations for Base^nDigits. (b=base, n=nDigits).

```
void printNumeration(int b, int n){
    int i, j=0;
    int *array = calloc(n, sizeof(int));

    if (array == NULL){
        printf("Allocation failed.\n");
        exit(0);
    }


    for (i=0; i<pow(b, n); i++){
        for (j=0; j<n; j++){
            printf("%d", array[j]);
            array[j]++;
            if (array[j] == n){
                array[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

You can also give some tips about a better solution if mine is completely wrong.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You increment each digit in the inner loop. You can either increment the last digit continuously (and calculate the carry) until the first digiit wraps (think odometer) or you can print `i` with the usual code to print integer of a cerian base for each pass.

Comment: @MOehm I did not understand 80% of what you said...sorry lol

Comment: @2501 maybe the correct way to do what I'm trying to...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, **Do not use `pow` for integer numbers.** - *at least not without rounding*. `pow` uses an inexact floating point algorithm to do the exponentiation. There was just last week a question where there was an error because [`pow(10, 2)` was 99.9999999... which truncated to int was `99`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35802524/undesired-output-with-modulo-operator-and-pow/35802753#35802753).

That is, there might well be a platform, where `pow(2, 3)` as in your example results in `7.999999...`; as doubles are converted to integers by just *truncating* the decimals, this would mean that your code runs 7 loops instead of 8! The same would be still true for `double` comparison; 8.0 is still greater than 7.999999999999999. Thus we use [`round`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/round) to ensure that the resulting number is rounded correctly to *the nearest integer value* (8.0 in this case).

Also you'd want to count this number beforehand, not for every loop iteration.

We have 2 inner loops. First prints the numbers and second works backwards - if the `k`th digit is equal to `b` we set it to 0, we decrease k by 1 and increase now `k`th digit by one, and repeat.

Finally, remember to free the memory allocated by calloc.

```
void printNumeration(int b, int n) {
    int *digits = calloc(sizeof(int), n);
    int max = round(pow(b, n));
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j ++) {
            printf("%d", digits[j]);
        }
        int k = n - 1;
        digits[k] ++;
        while (k && digits[k] == b) {
            digits[k] = 0;
            k--;
            digits[k] ++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(digits);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the other guy, he gave a really good answer and effort, but I like more your function, this is more close to my code-style. Thank you a lot, that's exactly what I wanted to do. Best answer to you!

Comment: can you explain what round does tho, and also a better way where I don't use the pow function?

Comment: @THZ added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

> I did not understand 80% of what you said...

That's a bad ratio. Let me explain:

> You increment each digit in the inner loop.

You increment every digit unconditionally in the inner loop and wrap it if necessary. That means that your enumeration increments all digits in lockstep, yielding output such as 00, 11, 22, 00, 11, 2, ...

> You can either increment the last digit continuously (and calculate the carry) until the first digiit wraps (think odometer) ...

You can start with an array of all zeros. Print it. Increment the last digit. Check for overflow and if it overflows, set it to zero and increment the next digit, and so on. If the leftmost digit overflows, stop your enumeration. That's how an odometer (the mile/km counter) in a car works:

```
void printnum(int dig[], int n)
{
    static const char *digit = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    while (n--) putchar(digit[dig[n]]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int enumerate(int base, int n)
{
    int dig[100] = {0};
    int count = 0;

    for (;;) {
        int i = 0;

        while (i < n && dig[i] == base) {
            dig[i++] = 0;
            dig[i]++;
        }
        if (i == n) break;

        printnum(dig, n);

        dig[0]++;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

> or you can print i with the usual code to print integer of a cerian base for each pass.

Your enumeration yields `base^n` numbers. (You probably shouldn't calculate this power with the floating-point function `pow`, though.) You can loop over all these numbers as you do in your code and then print out the number in the given base. The usual approach, of which you can find zillions of examples here on SO, is to fill an array from the right with the remainders of subsequent divisions by base until the number is zero. Here, you want all digits printed, so you should do the division `n` times, regardless of the zero numerator.

```
int enumerate(int base, int n)
{
    int max = 1;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) max *= base;

    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        int buf[n];

        int j = i;
        int m;

        for (m = 0; m < n; m++) {
            buf[m] = j % base;
            j /= base;
        }

        printnum(buf, n);        
    }

    return max;
}
```

There are even more ways to solve this. Hours of fun!

Comment: I really like more the first solution. I just don't understand 2 things:
1) How should I write that for cycle with conditions and not like you wrote? ('for(;;)')
2) Why you take note of 'count' var and also why return it?

Comment: (1) The condition is evaluated in the middle of the loop; it is more practical to break the (nominally infinite) loop than to evaluate a condition when entering the loop. (Rewriting the code with an entry condition is, of course, a nice exercise `:)`) (2) It isn't strictly necessary, but it's a sensible return value and a quick check whether all possibilities have been printed.